# Do child nodes inherit font-size from :root?

Tags: html, css

If I reset the `font-size` for everything to zero, to eliminate all unintended whitespace, and then use the `:root` pseudo-class to set the font-size to `12pt`, child elements of `html` still have a font-size of zero and need to have their font-size properties specified directly. Why? Do child nodes not inherit the font size of root?

```css
* {
  font-size: 0;
}
:root {
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: silver;
}
```

```html
 <h1>My Heading</h1>
```

```css
* {
  font-size: 0;
}
:root {
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: silver;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}
```

```html
 <h1>My Heading</h1>
```

Comment: inherit is only considered if nothing specified which is not the case when you specify the font using *

Comment: from the duplicate: *Any declaration that matches element directly will get priority over the property that's inherited from the element's parent.*